# Access external hashmap value inside MongoDB aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a Ruby on Rails project, I have a MongoDB collection called Events:

```
{
  _id: 1, title: Event-1, timestamp: 1567687654, data: {"a": 23,"b": 40}, machine_key: "key1",
  _id: 2, title: Event-2, timestamp: 1567687656, data: {"a": 11,"b": 49}, machine_key: "key2",
  _id: 3, title: Event-3, timestamp: 1567687658, data: {"a": 10,"b": 50}, machine_key: "key2",
  ...
}
```

There is an external hashmap (not a MongoDB collection) having following structure -

```
machine_map = {"key1" : {"code": "M1", "type": "Type A"}, "key2" : {"code": "M2", "type": "Type B"},...... }
```

I want to use an aggregation pipeline on the collection to produce such a result:

```
db.Events.aggregate([
 { $match: { title: "Event-1" } },
 { $project: { title: 1, machine_key: 1, machine_data: machine_map["$machine_key"] } }
])
```

How can I get data from external hashmap `machine_map` using the `machine_key` field?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to "iterate" over the object and use Mongo operators to match the value. There are several different ways to do this, here is one example:

```
db.Events.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            title: "Event-1"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            title: 1,
            machine_key: 1,
            machine_data: {
                $arrayElmAt: [
                    {
                        $reduce: {
                            input: {
                                $filter: {
                                    input: {$objectToArray: machine_map},
                                    as: "m",
                                    cond: {$eq: ["$$m.k", "$machine_key"]}
                                }
                            },
                            initialValue: {},
                            in: "$$this.v"
                        }
                    },
                    0
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hello Tom, thank you for help. I tried this solution and it is working correctly. However the hashmap `machine_map` has around 10,000 objects and the query is taking too long to execute ( ~18 sec ). Do let me know if we can have a faster solution for this.

Comment: Did the aggregation run fast prior to thischange? is `machine_map` a very large object? With the current object structure there's no way to improve performance as Mongo requires us to iterate on the entire object in order to find a match, there's no "break" loop feature that exists. Is storing that hashmap as a collection and then `$lookup`ing a viable solution? i'm assuming you can't just store it in the original collection due to large scale updates or some other reason.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a [$switch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/#switch-aggregation) expressions based on that hashmap.  Build the switch with ruby and submit it with the pipeline.

```
{$project: {
   machine_data: {
       $switch: {
          branches: [
             {case: {$eq:["machine_key","key1"]}, then: {"code": "M1", "type": "Type A"}},
             {case: {$eq:["machine_key","key2"]}, then: {"code": "M2", "type": "Type B"}},
          ...
          ]
       }
   }
}}
```